# How does JDBC DataSource works?

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

I wondered how works method **getConnection()** at DataSource? I assume that DataSource calling **DriverManager.getConnection** every time when we call **DataSource.getConnection** with our properties that we setting in DataSource. Is that true?

Comment: Could you please help to add in your codes?

Comment: @ChanGuanYu no code, theoretical question.  I just want to know that contains method DataSource.getConnection for create connection. Is that using DriverManager under?

Comment: A `javax.sql.DataSource` is an _interface_ it does nothing by itself, how or what it does depends on the concrete implementation, as long as it conforms to the JDBC requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to your question can be deduced from the `DataSource` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html).

> *"The `DataSource` interface is implemented by a driver vendor. There are three types of implementations:*
>
> - *Basic implementation -- produces a standard `Connection` object*
> - *Connection pooling implementation -- produces a `Connection` object that will automatically participate in connection pooling. This
>   implementation works with a middle-tier connection pooling manager.*
> - *Distributed transaction implementation -- produces a `Connection` object that may be used for distributed transactions and almost always
>   participates in connection pooling. This implementation works with a
>   middle-tier transaction manager and almost always with a connection
>   pooling manager.*"

Thus:

> I wondered how works method `getConnection()` at `DataSource`?

It is vendor specific, and depends on the type of implementation that the vendor provides.

> I assume that `DataSource` calling `DriverManager.getConnection` every time when we call `DataSource.getConnection` with our properties that we setting in `DataSource`. Is that true?

Not necessarily.  For example, `DataSource.getConnection()` *could* return the same `Connection` object each time it is called.  Or more plausibly, it could return a new `Connection` proxy for an underlying database pool connection that has been recycled.  Furthermore, that `DriverManager` method is not necessarily called to get the connection.

If you want to know how a specific `DataSource` works, you would need to look at the vendor documentation ... or alternatively its source code.

Comment: _"DataSource.getConnection() could return the same Connection object each time it is called."_ although technically possible, doing that would violate the JDBC requirements that a connection returned by a data source should behave the same as if it was a new physical connection (that is, after `close()` all derived objects are closed, and the connection behaves as a closed connection). This is why connection pools generally use some form of proxy or wrapping connection, so the proxy behaves as closed, while the underlying physical connection is returned to the pool for reuse.

Comment: That is a good point.  Updated.